# Kivy Toggle buttons erratic behavior

Tags: python, kivy, togglebutton

Trying to translate a checklist (actually represented in xml) from tkinter to kivy. I gave up doing it with CheckBox and switched to ToggleButtons. This worked -- after a fashion. Unfortunately the toggles come unchecked or checked seemingly at random. I'm sure that I've made a basic error, but I can't see it.

```
    import kivy
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

    class ButtonList(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(ButtonList, self).__init__(**kwargs)

            listRoot = [
                "Controls",
                "Ballast",
                "Straps",
                "Instruments",
                "Trim",
                "Canopy",
                "Brake"
            ]

            self.buttons = []
            for child in listRoot:
                b = ToggleButton(text=child, state="normal")
                self.buttons.append(b)
                self.add_widget(b)

            submit = Button(text="Submit", on_press=self.on_submit)
            self.add_widget(submit)

            self.output = Label(text="Output")
            self.add_widget(self.output)

        def on_submit(self, instance):
            out = "Selection: "
            for i in self.buttons:
                 if i.state == "down":
                    out += i.text + " "
            self.output.text = out


    class ButtonListApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return ButtonList()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        ButtonListApp().run()
```

and the  .kv

```
    <ButtonList>:
        cols: 1
```

My intention is to put the layout for the meat of my program into the kv file with two checklists (togglebutton lists) created by this python function. But first it needs to stop checking and unchecking values on its own.

```
    [INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event4> range touch major is 0 - 0
    [INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event10> range touch major is 0 - 0
    [INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event4> range touch minor is 0 - 0
    [INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event10> range touch minor is 0 - 0
```

Since it worked for watney, and I didn't think "range touch major 0 - 0" looked valid, I tried a different mousepad. Problem went away. I guess Kivy or Ubuntu doesn't like my mouse. Any suggestion as to fixes would be helpful.

Comment: I think the code is working fine, if I've understood your question. It's giving elements that are in the `down` state correctly at any point when you click submit.

Comment: Yes it is. But if you count to three, it 'clicks' or 'un-clicks' a few elements without regard for user input.

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5697 -- fixed it